# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

Hi I'm quite new to codeigniter. I have a code which was working fine few days ago, but when I opened it again it is giving me the error of page you requested not found. basically the code is about adding user in database. Kindly help me here and I need you suggestions. Here is my model, controller and view codes.

**Model file**

**Userinsert_model.php**

```
<?php
class Userinsert_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){

$this->db->insert('students', $data);
}

public function datafetch(){
    $fetch= $this->db->get('students'); 
    return $fetch->result();

}

}



?>
```

**Controller file**

**Userinsert_controller.php**

```
<?php

class Userinsert_controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Userinsert_model');
}
function index() {

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('dmobile', 'Mobile No.', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('daddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('Userinsert_view');
} else {
$data = array(
'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
'Student_Mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'),
'Student_Address' => $this->input->post('daddress')
);
$this->Userinsert_model->form_insert($data);
$data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
$this->load->view('Userinsert_view', $data);
}
}
public function fetch() {

    $this->load->model('Userinsert_model');

        $data["all_data"]= $this->Userinsert_model->datafetch();
$this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('Usershow_view', $data);  
}
}



?>
```

**View file**

**Userinsert_view.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<?php echo form_open('Userinsert_controller'); ?>

<h1>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter</h1><hr/>
<?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
<CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo form_label('Student Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dname'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Mobile No. :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dmobile'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dmobile', 'name' => 'dmobile', 'placeholder' => '10 Digit Mobile No.')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Address :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('daddress'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'daddress', 'name' => 'daddress')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
<div id="fugo">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show how config/routes.php look like, 404 error might be cause due to misconfiguration in the routes

Comment: let me show you

Comment: @Kuru
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: @dawoodbasharat I highly appreciate to read this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: rename Userinsert_controller.php to userinsert_controller.php

Comment: @amarnath thankyou i will read it

Comment: change `<?php echo form_open('Userinsert_controller'); ?>` to `<?php echo form_open('Userinsert_controller/index'); ?>`

Comment: @Shihas i did what you said but the problem remains

Comment: can you please show the error message?

Comment: @Shihas im using this url to open my form
http://localhost/codeIgniter/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/index.php/Userinsert

and after filling the form when i press enter it goes to this url
http://localhost/codeIgniter/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/index.php/index.php/Userinsert

and say 404 error page not found

Comment: In `config.php` did you remove index.php from `$config['index_page']` ?

Comment: do i need to remove 'index.php' file from config.php?

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
 it is in my config.php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `config.php` replace

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Happy coding (Y)

Comment: can i ask some more help from you?

Comment: Definitely.. You can come up with new questions, If you wanna fix some bugs.

Comment: @ i have some new question its related to sessions! if you dont mind can i just have your email or any other thing like that through which i can contact you? please don't mind if you find it inconvenient

Answer (score 1):

Rename `class Userinsert_controller extends CI_Controller {`
 to `class Userinsert extends CI_Controller {`
 and then visit the site via example.com/index.php/userinsert

Comment: Sir still same issue

Comment: Is the Controller in `applications/controller`?

Comment: yes thats why i named it Userinsert_controller just to make it easy for me to remember. but i changed the name Userinsert

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot from your folder structure?

Comment: sorry i didn't get it!! do i need to send you the screen shot of my files in which folders they are or do need to give you screen shots of config files?

Comment: a Screenshot of the Full folder structure. In best case with Files

Comment: how can i upload a screen shot in comments @lars

Comment: @amarnath i hope i get your point and posted the pic you needed

Answer (score 1):

Your `application/config/routes.php` must look like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There are three reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router which controller/method to use if those
| provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
|   $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
|
| This is not exactly a route, but allows you to automatically route
| controller and method names that contain dashes. '-' isn't a valid
| class or method name character, so it requires translation.
| When you set this option to TRUE, it will replace ALL dashes in the
| controller and method URI segments.
|
| Examples: my-controller/index -> my_controller/index
|       my-controller/my-method -> my_controller/my_method
*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

/* CUSTOM ROUTES */
$route['userinsert'] = 'Userinsert';
```

Basically you need to have the below route.

```
$route['userinsert'] = 'Userinsert';
```

Comment: let me check it again

Comment: it is exactly the same except this line

/* CUSTOM ROUTES */
$route['userinsert'] = 'Userinsert';

Comment: how do you visit the site? With which url?

Comment: here is the url
http://localhost/codeIgniter/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/index.php/Userinsert

Comment: it used the url you suggested me but issue remains

Comment: sir thankyyou very much for your help you suggested me some new ways of finding errors. i will surely look forward to them next time. Thankyou again sir